# Magento2.4.2 in Elasticsearch 7 reindex not working

Tags: blocks, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2, page

We have installing magento2.4.2 with Elasticsearch 7. reindex not running. facing some issues:

***Catalog Search index process unknown error:***

```
 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"},"status":400}
```

Comment: Check which product name is empty. Some required field value pass empty to ES.

Comment: Es mapped and Successfully tested but i run the reindex comments showing this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ElasticSearch version is that issue of version .

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Magento 2.4.2 requires elasticsearch 7.9 .

Check Version using Curl from Command Line

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

Comment: now we have using magento2.4.2 and elasticsearch  7.9 but showing same issues.

Comment: Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"},"status":400}

Comment: now its showing this issues please help on this issues -  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"name cannot be empty string"},"status":400}

Comment: **curl -XGET 'elasticsearch-host:9200'**

please replace the `elasticsearch-host` and share the output of elasticsearch .

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
i have removed without name in unwanted attributes. and run the reindex its working.
[image]